# Sine to Square only with a MCU

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, sine, square

I know several topics already talks about this but I didn't find my answer yet.
Is it possible to convert a sine wave to a square wave only with a MCU ? 
Both wave are only a matter of changing frequency.
Is the MCU capable of flag the top and bottom wave for example ?
In my case I would like to use a STM32.
My goal is quite straiht forward, when the sine wave is at top, I want a top square, and when at bottom, at bottom on the square.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"?

Comment: My tool generate a sine wave and I want to read this sine wave with the MCU in order to generate a square wave

Comment: what should be the correspondence between the sine and the result?

Comment: @vib A hardware solution would be much easier to do and more reliable.

Comment: UM.. "Is the MCU capable of flag the top and bottom wave for example ?".... Yes! ... Next!

Comment: An analog coparator would be much more appropriate, I think.

Comment: There are plenty of MCUs that have on-board analog comparators. As to your particular one, you can read the datasheet to find out if it has such a function. Otherwise add an external one and, in any case, bias it appropriately so that the sine wave stays within the input range (usually less than or equal to the power supply rails).

Comment: The frequency of this sine wave is relevant...

Comment: OK thank you. And the ADC could do that also isn't it? It seems built for this

Comment: why not just read the ADC and flip a gpio on and off based on the read value?

Comment: You need to state the frequency and amplitude of the sine wave, and also explain if it is "clean" or "noisy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your question is pretty vague so this may not be a good answer. You can run it into a digital input and program the MCU to have an output go high when the input is high and go low when the input is low. This solution assumes that:

- The sine wave meets the VIH and VIL requirements of the MCU inputs.
- The sine wave frequency is << than the MCU clock.
- Your application can handle the clock being delayed.
- Your application can handle a slightly off duty cycle.

From the information given, I don't know if these requirements are met.